# Random Exception : Futures timed out after Exception in Spark Jobs

Tags: java, apache-spark

Getting the following error on running the spark Job on Spark 2.0.
The error is Random in nature & does not occur all the time. 
Once the tasks are being created most of them are completed properly while a few gets hung & throws the following error after a while.

I have tried increasing the following properties spark.executor.heartbeatInterval & spark.network.timeout but of no use.

```
17/07/23 20:46:35 WARN NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@597e9d16,BlockManagerId(driver, 128.164.190.35, 38337))] in 1 attempts
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:518)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1857)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:547)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:81)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: checkout gc of your task executions. May be some of executors are stuck at gc's STW pause and can't sent heartbeat.

Comment: Yes, the problem is indeed due to GC as it used to pause the tasks, changing the default GC to G1GC reduced the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is indeed due to GC as it used to pause the tasks, changing the default GC to G1GC reduced the problem. Thanks

XX:+UseG1GC

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/05/28/tuning-java-garbage-collection-for-spark-applications.html